# how do i direct servlet mapping to be directed to this url

Tags: tomcat, servlets, path

i need to direct url in my web server to be :

```
http://localhost:8080/console/myws/mymethod
```

i have servlet class called MyServlet
with some methods ( that in the end are web services converted with JAXWS) 
how can i map this servlet to be in the tomcat server if it possible without changing the servlet class name:

```
http://localhost:8080/console/myws/mymethod
```

here is my web.xml configuration i just can't make it work.  i define console to be my Context root   without the "/" just console

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
     </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jax-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jax-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            90
        </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

also how can i debug the configuration in tomcat to check what i did wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `/console` is the context path and the `/mymethod` is the path info, then you need to map the servlet on `/myws/*`.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yourServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet class and name is totally independent from the URL pattern you choose, so you don't need to change it as well at all.

Comment: where exactly i define the /concole ? context path , its not class or servlet just needs to be part or the url

Comment: Uh, just in your webapp's `<Context>`. In most IDEs like Eclipse it defaults to the project name and is configureable as "context root" in *Web Project Settings* of project's properties.

Comment: its not working , im getting 404 , let me update the question
can't i do just :
<url-pattern>/concole/myws/mymethod/*</url-pattern>

Comment: If your project is deployed in context root, then you should rather map the servlet on `/concole/*` depending on the purpose of your request URL (which you wasn't clear about in your initial question at all).

Comment: the request url that the outside world see has to be :  
http://localhost:8080/console/myws/mymethod
i mapped the Context root to "console"

Comment: So, your web application is deployed to http://localhost:8080/console? Then mapping the servlet on `/myws/*` should do. If you still get a 404, then it simply means that the servlet failed to load (read the server logs for clues) or that you actually typo'ed the URL (please note that concole != console).